# css sheets in each frame

Tags: html, css

I working on a very old website that I am trying to update and I seem to be running into some issues.

My biggest problem seems that it seems that the same style sheets need to be included in each frame instead of placing them in the header frame and effecting the whole page.

Is there any way around this? I have some bootstrap I wanted to include and don't really want to declare those a billion times.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @ZachSaucier An example of including stylesheets?

Comment: Did my response answer your question, or is there something else I can help you with?

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot be applied across `frames`, I believe.

Main thing is, `frames` are depreciated. First thing you need to do is remove them. However, given it's an old site you just want to update, removing might not be an option.

Comment: I know frames are deprecated. I could not find any research to see if there was a way to replace them with something...it's like they used a frame for the header, one for the sidebar and then one for the main content. Do you know of something I could replace this with?

Comment: Put it all in one sheet. User `<header>`, `<aside>`, and `<main>`. Or `<div id="header">`, `<div id="sidebar">`,`<div id="main">`.

Comment: even if the main content is being switched out? I know the header and sidebar stay pretty content, but the content seems to be switching out

Comment: Absolutely. Granted, you could use an `iframe` for the content, but you shouldn't.

Comment: If you need to change out content frequently, use a CMS like WordPress.

Comment: we are not using word press, the backend has already been built and works, I'm just trying to find a solution around the frame situation.

Comment: The solution is to declare CSS on every frame, or not to use frames, I'm afraid.